# Why does Powershell ISE console display $args values incorrectly

Tags: powershell

When I am stopped at a breakpoint in ISE, the console displays all my current variables correctly, except for $args.

Consider the following (very simple) script:

```
$args.Count
$args[0]
$x = $args.Count
$y = $args[0]
$x
$y
Write-Output "done"
```

I run the script as follows in PS ISE and set a breakpoint on the last line.

```
test.ps1 "abc"
```

I get the following (correct) output:

```
1
abc
1
abc
```

But then if I type the following in the ISE console, while still on the breakpoint:

```
$args.Count
$args[0]
```

it displays:

```
0
```

Namely, the console window thinks $args is empty. Why is this?

If I display the other script variables in the console, "$x" and "$y", they display correctly.

Comment: Because debugger does not pass any arguments to the script block you type at debugging prompt.

Comment: The scope of `$args` in your script is `script`.  Imagine your script is one big function.  `$args` isn't defined at a REPL.

Comment: Because `powershell -command "echo $args.Count"` returns `0`. Read more in [about_Automatic_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-6#args).

Comment: TheIncorrigible: But $x has the same scope and it is displayed OK in the console. JosefZ: You are just pointing out another way of outputting $args.Count. This doesn't explain the reason for the behavior. PetSerAl: I am not passing arguments to the script from the console. I am displaying their current values.

Comment: *I am not passing arguments to the script from the console. I am displaying their current values.* So, you did get zero arguments exactly because you pass zero arguments. Although I suspect, that by *script* you mean something else then me. I suggest you to type this command in debug prompt: ``"This script is currently executing: |$($MyInvocation.MyCommand.ScriptBlock)|.`nAnd this is arguments passed to it: |$args|."``

Comment: I pass an argument when I first start test.ps1. My question is about what I type at the console when on the break-point. At that time I am not trying to pass arguments to the script. I am only trying to display the current values of the script's arguments.

Comment: @PetSerAl When I typed what you asked at the breakpoint, I got: "And this is arguments passed to it: ||." Even though I started the script with one argument by calling: test.ps1 "abc".

Comment: And what was after `This script is currently executing:` part?

Comment: I had an type error before. Now it says: This script is currently executing: |$($MyInvocation.MyCommand.ScriptBlock)|.`nAnd this is arguments passed to it: |$args|.
abc.    So this command shows the argument correctly. But I still don't know why just typing $args[0] does not.